# Trying to parse a response in doInbackground using asynctask

Tags: android, mysql

I want to retrieve a events comments from a MySQL database and display it. But every time I run it, it shows data can't be parsed. I'm kinda lost on how to parse a parameter through async task doInBackground function. The problem may be in this function. Any help would be appreciated.

Any example of passing a parameter and getting the data a list view will help a lot.

This is my classes.

```
public class Comments {
    int commentID;
    String UserName, Time, Comment;

public int getCommentID() {
    return commentID;
}

public void setCommentID(int commentID) {
    this.commentID = commentID;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return UserName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {UserName = userName;}

public String getTime() {
    return Time;
}

    public void setTime(String time) {
        Time = time;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return Comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        Comment = comment;
    }
}
```

This is my downloader

```
public class CommentDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

Context c;
String urlAdress;
ListView lv;

public CommentDownloader(Context c, String urlAdress, ListView lv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.urlAdress = urlAdress;
    this.lv = lv;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.downloadData();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);

    if(s==null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(c,"No Comments",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else
    {
        //CALL DATA PARSER TO PARSE
        CommentDataParser parser=new CommentDataParser(c,lv,s);
        parser.execute();

    }
}

private String downloadData() {
    try {

        IDSaver id = new IDSaver();
        String ID = String.valueOf(id.getIdSaver());
        URL url = new URL(urlAdress);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
        String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("EventID", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ID, "UTF-8");
        bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    HttpURLConnection con = Connector.connect(urlAdress);
    if (con == null) {
        return null;
    }

    InputStream is = null;
    try {

        is = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line = null;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        if (br != null) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line + "\n");
            }

            br.close();

        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return response.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}}
```

This is the DataParser

```
public class CommentDataParser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer>{
    Context c;
    ListView lv;
    String jsonData;

ProgressDialog pd;
ArrayList<Comments> comments=new ArrayList<>();

public CommentDataParser(Context c, ListView lv, String jsonData) {
    this.c = c;
    this.lv = lv;
    this.jsonData = jsonData;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Parse");
    pd.setMessage("Parsing...Please wait");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.parseData();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    pd.dismiss();
    if(result==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        //CALL ADAPTER TO BIND DATA
        CommentCustomAdapter adapter=new CommentCustomAdapter(c,comments);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

private int parseData()
{
    try {
        JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(jsonData);
        JSONObject jo=null;

        comments.clear();
        Comments c =null;

        for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);

            int id=jo.getInt("CommentID");
            String name=jo.getString("UserName");
            String time=jo.getString("TimeStamp");
            String comment =jo.getString("Comment");

            c=new Comments();
            c.setCommentID(id);
            c.setUserName(name);
            c.setTime(time);
            c.setComment(comment);

            comments.add(c);


        }

        return 1;


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;


  }
}
```

This is my custom adapter

```
public class CommentCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context c;
    ArrayList<Comments> comments;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CommentCustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Comments> comments) {
        this.c = c;
        this.comments = comments;

        //INITIALIE
        inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return comments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return comments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return comments.get(position).getCommentID();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_model,parent,false);
        }

        TextView nameTxt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NameTextView);
        TextView commentTxt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CommmenttextView);
        TextView timeTxt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TimeDateTextView);

        nameTxt.setText(comments.get(position).getUserName());
        commentTxt.setText(comments.get(position).getComment());
        timeTxt.setText(comments.get(position).getTime());

        //ITEM CLICKS
        //convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            //public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(c,comments.get(position).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //}
        //});

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here is the php

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$id = $_POST["EventID"];
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Comment.CommentID, Comment.Comment, Comment.TimeStamp, User.Lname AS 'UserName' FROM Comment, User WHERE EventID like '$id' AND Comment.UserID = User.UserID ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC;");
if($query)
{
While($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
$flag[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode($flag));
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Thnx for the help.
errors

```
08-10 23:10:26.766 16909-16909/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
08-10 23:10:26.766 16909-16909/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
08-10 23:10:26.861 1602-1673/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '398f66b com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1/com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1.EventDetailActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-10 23:10:26.861 1602-1673/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'e72f04d com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1/com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1.MainMenuActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-10 23:10:26.959 16931-16939/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
08-10 23:10:27.084 16946-16946/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-10 23:10:27.437 16952-16952/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-10 23:10:27.479 16954-16954/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-10 23:10:27.519 16956-16956/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-10 23:10:27.567 16958-16958/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-10 23:10:27.589 16960-16960/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-10 23:10:27.625 16962-16962/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-10 23:10:27.734 16964-16964/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-10 23:10:27.774 16966-16966/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-10 23:10:27.798 16968-16968/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-10 23:10:27.840 16970-16970/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-10 23:10:28.814 1258-1697/? E/audio_hw_generic: Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000
08-10 23:10:30.673 16981-16981/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
08-10 23:10:30.673 16981-16981/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
08-10 23:10:31.630 17008-17008/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
08-10 23:10:31.630 17008-17008/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
08-10 23:10:37.147 17082-17082/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
08-10 23:10:37.147 17082-17082/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
08-10 23:10:37.239 17082-17110/? E/art: Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1
08-10 23:10:37.366 17091-17091/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
08-10 23:10:37.366 17091-17091/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
08-10 23:10:40.461 1248-1667/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-10 23:10:41.295 16931-16931/com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-10 23:10:41.295 16931-16931/com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-10 23:10:43.052 16931-16931/com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-10 23:10:43.052 16931-16931/com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-10 23:11:45.227 16931-16931/com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-10 23:11:45.227 16931-16931/com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-10 23:11:47.578 16931-16931/com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-10 23:11:47.578 16931-16931/com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-10 23:12:37.587 18730-18730/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
08-10 23:12:37.587 18730-18730/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
08-10 23:12:37.644 1602-1673/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '26ec53a com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1/com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1.MainMenuActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-10 23:12:37.644 1602-1673/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '2e54f60 com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1/com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1.EventDetailActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-10 23:12:37.644 1602-1673/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'f3731b6 com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1/com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1.CommentActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-10 23:12:37.937 18761-18761/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-10 23:12:43.788 1258-1698/? E/audio_hw_generic: Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000
```

Comment: Is there any extra field you are not parsing?

Comment: Plus add the error stack trace

Comment: That error stack has alot of stuff must i copy all of them

Comment: Yes. Copy the whole stack trace.

Comment: I dt put up the stack trace